# i have made changes to the code

Tags: c++, qt

> this is my method and it does not work.

```
void ApplicationUI::Post(const QString &id,const QString &name,const QString &surname,const QString &grade, const QString &dob,const QString &language,const QString &school, const QString &gender,const QString &cellno,const QString &registrationDate)
{
    this->connection = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(this->connection, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(postFinished()));

    QUrl url("http://172.27.15.7/BB10_Scripts/Registration.php");
    QUrl postParams;
    postParams.addQueryItem("id",id);
    postParams.addQueryItem("name", name);
    postParams.addQueryItem("surname",surname);
    postParams.addQueryItem("grade",grade);
    postParams.addQueryItem("dob",dob);
    postParams.addQueryItem("language",language);
    postParams.addQueryItem("school",school);
    postParams.addQueryItem("gender",gender);
    postParams.addQueryItem("cellno",cellno);
    postParams.addQueryItem("registrationDate",registrationDate);

    QByteArray data;
    data.append(postParams.data);
    data.remove(0,1);

    QNetworkRequest req;
    req.setUrl(url);
    req.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    this->connection->post(req,postParams.encodedQuery());());    
    bool ok = QObject::connect(connection, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(postFinished()));
    Q_ASSERT(ok);
    Q_UNUSED(ok);
    qDebug() << "Connection is success : ? : " << ok;
}
```

> i get the message
>
> Connection is success : ? :  true 
>    Process 476930267 (CascadesProject) terminated SIGSEGV code=1 fltno=11 >ip=79f70ce2 >(/base/usr/lib/qt4/lib/libQtNetwork.so.4.8.5@_ZNK13QNetworkReply5errorEv+0x9) >mapaddr=00060ce2. ref=00000004 bdslot=1

Comment: There are a lot of parameters named `"id"`. Also, you send the request twice. Also, you create a new `QNetworkAccessManager` for every call to your `Post` method. Also, you put your `postParams` in `data` but don't send `data` but `postParams.encodedQuery()`; decide for one.

Comment: here is what i have now. but the same message still persist

Comment: i have made changesto the code above but still it does the same. please advise

Comment: You haven't addressed all of @leemes points, so no wonder it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

```
postParams.addQueryItem("id", id);
postParams.addQueryItem("name", name);
postParams.addQueryItem("surname", surname);
postParams.addQueryItem("grade", grade);
postParams.addQueryItem("dob", dob);
postParams.addQueryItem("language", language);
postParams.addQueryItem("school", school);
postParams.addQueryItem("gender", gender);
postParams.addQueryItem("cellno", cellno);
postParams.addQueryItem("registrationDate",registrationDate);

QNetworkRequest request;
request.setUrl(QUrl("http://172.27.15.7/BB10_Scripts/Registration.php?"));

bool res;
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
Q_UNUSED(res);
this->reply = connection->post(request, postParams.encodedQuery());
res = QObject::connect(this->reply, SIGNAL(finished()),this, SLOT(postFinished()));
Q_ASSERT(res);
Q_UNUSED(res);
qDebug() << "Connection is success : ? : " << res;
```

Comment: thanks for your positive input. i cracked it at last